# Sorting and Analyzing Arrays In C

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, pointers, bubble-sort

I made a little dice game where I should get Grand if I throw 5 times the same number and a Poker if I throw 4 times the same number.

My problem is that my code only work with "1" and "2" if I try to get a Poker with 4 it doesn't count

```
#include <stdio.h>

void abfrage(int wurf[], int size){
    int i;
        for (i=0; i<size; i++){
            printf("Würfel %i: ", i+1);
            scanf("%i", &wurf[i]);
        }
}

// switch int*
void swap(int *xp, int *yp) 
{ 
    int temp = *xp; 
    *xp = *yp; 
    *yp = temp; 
} 
// Sort the array
void bubbleSort(int wurf[], int size) 
{ 
    int i, j; 
    for (i = 0; i < size-1; i++){          
        for (j = 0; j < size-i-1; j++){ 
            if (wurf[j] > wurf[j+1])
            {
                swap(&wurf[j], &wurf[j+1]); 
            }
        }
    }
} 

void arrayausgabe(int wurf[], int size){
    int u = 0;
    for (u=0;u<size;u++) {
        printf("array nummer %i: ", u); // err with "&"
        printf("%i \n", wurf[u]);
    }
}

void bewertung(int wurf[]){
    int *x;
    x = wurf;

    if (*x==*(x+1)==*(x+2)==*(x+3)==*(x+4)) {
        printf("Grand");
    }else if (*x==*(x+1)==*(x+2)==*(x+3) || *(x+1)==*(x+2)==*(x+3)==*(x+4)) {
        printf("Poker");
    }else if ((*x==*(x+1)==*(x+2) && *(x+3)==*(x+4) )||(*(x+2)==*(x+3)==*(x+4) &&  *x==*(x+1))) {
        printf("Full House");
    }else {
        printf("HAAA Verloren");
    }
}

int main() {
    int  wurf[5];
    printf("Programm Würfelspiel\nGrand\tgleiche Augenzahl auf allen 5 Würfeln\nPoker\tgleiche Augenzahl auf 4 Würfeln\nFull House\tgleiche und 2 gleiche Augenzahlen\n\nBitte gibt deine gewürfelten zahlen ein\n");
    abfrage(wurf, 5);
    bubbleSort(wurf, 5);
    arrayausgabe(wurf, 5);
    bewertung(wurf);
}
```

I'm in freshman year so sorry if the code look's a bit trashy

Comment: Could you add comments explaining what different sections of this code is attempting to do?  And explain a little clearer what the problem is, and how one would go about re-creating it?

Comment: Doing `*(x+1)` is completely unnecessary and confusing; access the array with array notation: `wurf[0] == wurf[1]`...

Comment: Didn't have time to inspect all the code but there is a definite error in your bubble sort function. (1) Revisit the upper & lower bounds for the `for` loops and (2) the indexes of the conditional line `if (wurf[j] > wurf[j+1])` as well.

Comment: You should also check the return value from `scanf()` to make sure it read the number of fields you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This logic:

```
if (*x==*(x+1)==*(x+2)==*(x+3)==*(x+4)) {
```

does not do what you expect in C (though it does in Python): a comparison with `==` returns either 0 or 1, according to whether the values are different or equal. Chaining them doesn't check whether they're all equal to each other; instead, it checks if the first two are equal, and then compares the result of that equality (which can be 0 or 1) against the value of the third value, and so on.

You need to check each comparison separately:

```
if (wurf[0] == wurf[1] && wurf[0] == wurf[2] && wurf[0] == wurf[3] && wurf[0] == wurf[4]) {
```